# How to get AutoCAD file (.dwg) to view zoom pan and get entity on web application

Tags: c#, asp.net, autocad-plugin

I try to get show AutoCAD file (.dwg) to display file

And I need to view, pan, zoom and click to view entity

So now I use CadLib 4.0 in Win Application can be use,

but in Web Application it will can not be to do right that.

please hint to find this solution.

Answer (score 0):

Actually Autodesk offers a WebGL/HTML viewer that can embed on any webpage (or any app, desktop or mobile). No plugin or additional install is required.

You'll need to upload, translate, then show on your page. We have APIs for server and client side.

See complement documentation (and keys) at http://developer.autodesk.com

Answer (score 0):

Presten and Walmsley reported [here](http://through-the-interface.typepad.com/through_the_interface/2015/05/viewing-50-design-software-formats-from-a-web-page.html) and [here](http://adndevblog.typepad.com/cloud_and_mobile/2015/05/a360-widget.html) that you can use their viewr in order to do this. It can pan and zoom but maybe not be able to select entity. The guide :

> How to use: Render just the drop target for the widget
>
> Include widget.css
>       Include JQuery if it has not already been included on your website
>       Include widget.js
>       Instantiate adskViewerWidget()
>       Call init("#elementID", true) and pass the DOM element where you want the A360 Viewer Widget to be rendered and true to indicate that
>   only the drop target should be rendered.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>A360 Viewer Widget Embedding Example</title>
    <link href="https://360.autodesk.com/Content/css/a360Viewer/widget.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="https://360.autodesk.com/Scripts/a360Viewer/widget.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="a360ViewerWidget" style="width: 200px">
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var adskViewerWidget = adskViewerWidget();
        adskViewerWidget.Init('#a360ViewerWidget', true);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```